# Java read input/output print duplicate string to file

Tags: java, io

Hi I am working on this problem, Suppose a library is processing an input file containing the titles of books in order to identify duplicates. Write a program that reads all of the titles from an input file called bookTitles.inp and writes them to an output file called duplicateTitles.out. When complete, the output file should contain all titles that are duplicated in the input file. Note that the duplicate titles should be written once, even though the input file may
contain same titles multiple times. If there are not duplicate titles in the input file, the output file should be empty. Create the input file using Notepad or another text editor, with one title per line. Make sure you have a number of duplicates, including some with three or more copies.

So far I have this but It is printing the duplicates more than once if I change the order of the input file. Thanks.

```
      import java.io.*; 
      public class Library
      { 
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      { 
      String line3="";
      boolean dup = false;
      // PrintWriter object for output.txt 
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Ilyas\\Desktop\\tempBookTitles.txt"); 
      PrintWriter pw2 = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Ilyas\\Desktop\\duplicateTitles.txt");
      // BufferedReader object for input.txt 
      BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new 
      FileReader("C:\\Users\\Ilyas\\Desktop\\bookTitles.txt")); //read input file
      String line1 = br1.readLine(); 
      // loop for each line of input.txt 
      while(line1 != null) 
      {   
      boolean flag = false; 
      // BufferedReader object for output.txt 
      BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new 
      FileReader("C:\\Users\\Ilyas\\Desktop\\tempBookTitles.txt"));
      BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new 
      FileReader("C:\\Users\\Ilyas\\Desktop\\duplicateTitles.txt"));  //try 
      String line2 = br2.readLine(); 
        // loop for each line of output.txt 
        while(line2 != null) 
        { 
            if(line1.equals(line2)) 
            { 
                line3 = br3.readLine();
                flag = true;
                
                
                if(line1.equals(line3))
                {
                    line1 = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    pw2.println(line1);
                    pw2.flush();            
                    //break; 
                }
                }
            } 
            line2 = br2.readLine(); 
        } 
        // if flag = false 
        // write line of input.txt to output.txt 
        if(flag==false)
        {                                                
        pw.println(line1);                   //print to temp file, delete temp file at end
        pw.flush(); 
        } 
        line1 = br1.readLine(); 
        } 

        br1.close(); 
        pw.close(); 
        pw2.close();
        System.out.println("File operation performed successfully"); 
        } 
        }
```

Comment: i suggest you update your code to use a Map<String, Integer> where the key = the title, and the value = the number of times it appears.

If the title is already inside the map's keys, then increment the number of times it appears. 
if the title is not yet inside the map's keys, then put the number of times it appears to 1.

use the map to keep track how many times the title appears

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but I have not learned that yet just BufferedReader. We are only allowed to use stuff we learned.

Comment: you can use Map together with BufferedReader. Try to use Map, (or Set if you just need to know if the title is duplicated or not, without the need to know how many times it duplicates). 

Otherwise what data structure will you use to keep track of number of duplicates?

Comment: Can you use ArrayList or even a string array (String[] strings)?

Comment: no, thanks I think its solved

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make the program readable, and also make it smaller by breaking into chunks of methods.

See my suggestion below.

```
   private List<String> getAllTitles(String filepath){
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

        // read the file, 
        // for each of the titles, insert into the list

        return titles;
    }

    private Set<String> getDuplicates(List<String> titles){
        Set<String> alreadyReadSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> duplicateSet = new HashSet<>();

        for (String title : titles) {
            if(/*alreadyReadSet contains the title*/){
                // put title into duplicateList
            }
            // put the title into alreadyReadSet
        }
        return duplicateSet;
    }

    private void printDuplicateList(Collection<String> duplicateList){
        // print to a file
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I cant use ArrayList only BufferedReader or PrintWriter/FileWriter or scan..

Answer (score 0):

To solve it without maps, you can use method contains, instead of writing directly to output file, create a output variable String, and change

```
{
   pw2.println(line1);
   pw2.flush();  
}
```

for

```
if (!output.contains(line1+"\n"))
    output=output + line1+"\n"
```

and after the loop print output to the file

Comment: I tried that but it just printed it with a space lol, does if (!output.contains(line1+"\n")) mean if output does not contain line1? thanks

Comment: oh after the first while loop.. ah it might work I will test it tmro thanks

Comment: does if (!output.contains(line1+"\n")) mean if output does not contain line1? thanks

Comment: if (!output.contains(line1+"\n")) means if output does not contain line1 and a line return

Comment: thanks man what is your paypal I can send you a thank you token

Answer (score 0):

So I am sure you have solved your problem by now, but in case anyone else comes across this thread looking for advice...

I encountered this same problem in my schoolwork recently and it drove me nuts trying to solve it with the tools we had learned so far in the course (which did not include maps or ArrayList). I ended up looking into the documentation for BufferedReader; and using the mark(int readLimit) and reset() methods. I got 100% on the assignment, so I thought I would leave this tip here for others.